# Expected a right parenthesis in expression

Tags: fortran

```
xic = ac * x**2.D0 * ( (1.D0 / 3.D0) * (1.D0 - x) *  
      (1.D0 + 10.D0 * x + x** 2.D0) +  2.D0 * x * 
      (1.D0 - x) * Log(x) )
```

I was compiling the above code with  **fortran** and got one error

```
Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

what should i do?

Comment: You'd better use `x*x` or `x**2` instead of `x**2.D0` for better performance.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing line continuation characters. They differ slightly for free and fixed form Fortran. For free form, you need to use `&` at the end of the line:

```
xic = ac * x**2.D0 * ( (1.D0 / 3.D0) * (1.D0 - x) * &
                       (1.D0 + 10.D0 * x + x** 2.D0) &
                       + 2.D0 * x * (1.D0 - x) * Log(x) )
```

For fixed-format this can be done by e.g. `&` at the sixth column of the *following line*:

```
      xic = ac * x**2.D0 * ( (1.D0 / 3.D0) * (1.D0 - x) * 
     &                  (1.D0 + 10.D0 * x + x** 2.D0) 
     &                  + 2.D0 * x * (1.D0 - x) * Log(x) )
```

Alternatively, you can extend the maximum allowed characters by using (`gfortran`) `-ffree-line-length-0` or `-ffixed-line-length-0`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following methods to cut a long line in Fortran :
http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap01/continue.html